# How to upload file without OpenFileDialog shown

Tags: delphi, cef4delphi

In versions before 100, the Chromium1FileDialog method `[callback. Font (selectedAcceptFilter: Integer; const filePaths: TStrings)]` can directly add selected images without opening the file selection box.

However, after version 102, the `selectedAcceptFilter` parameter is no longer present.

[image: Image of debugging information]

How can I achieve the original function of directly returning selected images without opening the file selection box?

This my code (cpu64 is cef102, else is cef93):

```
procedure TFrameBaseWebBrowser.Chromium1FileDialog(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; mode: Cardinal;
  const title, defaultFilePath: ustring;
  const acceptFilters: TStrings; selectedAcceptFilter: Integer;
  const callback: ICefFileDialogCallback;
  out Result: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
  ATempFilePath:String;
var
  AFiles:TStringList;
begin
  uBaseLog.HandleException('TFrameFacebookWebSearchAPI.Chromium1FileDialog Begin');
  if FContentFiles.Count > 0 then
  begin
    AFiles:=TStringList.Create;
    uBaseLog.HandleException('TFrameFacebookWebSearchAPI.Chromium1FileDialog '
                           + ' title:' + title
                           + ' defaultFilePath:' + defaultFilePath
                           + ' acceptFilters:' + acceptFilters.Text
                           + ' selectedAcceptFilter:' + IntToStr(selectedAcceptFilter));
    try
      //如果是链接,则先下载再添加
      for I := 0 to FContentFiles.Count-1 do
      begin
        if SameText(Copy(FContentFiles[I],1,7),'http://')
        or SameText(Copy(FContentFiles[I],1,8),'https://') then
        begin
          ATempFilePath:=//System.IOUtils.TPath.GetTempPath()+
                          System.IOUtils.TPath.GetTempFileName()
                          +ExtractFileExt(GetFileNameFromUrl(FContentFiles[I]))
                          ;
          if uBaseHttpControl.DownloadImage(FContentFiles[I],ATempFilePath) then
          begin
            AFiles.Add(ATempFilePath);
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          AFiles.Add(FContentFiles[I]);
        end;
      end;
  //    AFiles.Add('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\你很弱.jpg');
  //    AFiles.Add('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\傲途演示视频.mp4');
  //    AFiles.Add('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\不要.jpg');
      {$IFDEF CPUX64}
        callback.Cont(AFiles);
      {$ELSE}
        callback.Cont(selectedAcceptFilter, AFiles);
      {$ENDIF}
      Result := True;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(AFiles);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)